# How to cancel correctly NSURLConncetion

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new to iOS dev.

I've declared `NSURLConnection* mImageUploadConnection` as instance member. 
And running following to create it.

```
mImageUploadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:someRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

The retain count is 2 after allocation, why ? (This maybe Apple inner stuff, right? I still need to release connection only once ?).

I'm releasing connection in

```
 - didFailWithError
 - connectionDidFinishLoading
```

methods, but I also need to cancel the connection is some case, when user pops from current navigation view. I.e. The cancellation can take place while the `mImageUploadConnection` hasn't finished or failed. I cancel connection in following way

```
if (mUploadeImagConnection != nil) {
    [mUploadeImageConnection cancel];  
    [mUploadeImagConnection release];
}
```

The connection gets cancelled correctly when is hasn't finished or failed.
But the last code snippet fails (bad access) when connection has finished successfully, i.e. it has been released once.

- The retain count of mUploadeImagConnection is 1 when cancelling after
  connection finished successfully, why it is so ???
- How can I check in last code snippet if connection status was
  successful, and don't send cancel message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your ivar to `nil` after you have released it.

Comment: I was doing the same only through Utility class i.e. by passing connection to some method and releasing, assigning to nil inside that method. And it was not working at all. But doing it directly in he same code helped. Will mark your answer as correct. Actually nil should not be assigned in the Utiliy method as the Object pointer is copied. Yeah shame on me !